# Mongodb query from primary replica only

Tags: mongodb

I recently added read replicas in my mongodb. But now in many APIs, we are creating a document, then querying the same document and doing some processing there. Problem here is that the query is happening to read replicas where the document has not been synced yet and hence my APIs are failing. Is there a way I can specify in queries to run it on master/primary replica?

`User.findOne({email: 'abc@gmail.com'}).specifyToReadFromMaster()`

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [cursor.readConcern()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.readConcern/)

Comment: Thanks alot, documentation tells that it will solve my problem, I am trying this in code.

Comment: By default all reads and writes happen from replica set's primary only. You can specify read preference to control from where the reads should happen.